# Why is the last column isn't showing in my table?

Tags: tables

I created a table with 4 columns :

```
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Test function}                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Study domain}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Formula}                                                                                                                                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Global minimum}                                                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{} Rastrigin\\\textasciitilde{}( dim = n ) \end{tabular} & $-5.12 \leq x_i \leq 5.12$                 & $f(x_1 \cdots x_n) = 10n + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 -10cos(2\pi x_i))$                                                                                                       & $ \text{minimum at }f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                        \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{}Ackley\\\textasciitilde{}( dim = 2 ) \end{tabular}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$-5 \leq x_i \leq 5$ } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textasciitilde{}$f(x_0 \cdots x_2) = -20 exp(-0.2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i^2}) - exp(\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n cos(2\pi x_i)) + 20 + e$ } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\text{minimum at }f(0, 0) = 0$ }                                                                                                                                                           \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{} Rosenbrock\\( dim=n ) \end{tabular}                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$ \mathbb{R}^{N}$ }    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\$f(x_1 \cdots x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (100(x_i^2 - x_{i+1})^2 + (1-x_i)^2)$ \end{tabular}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$ \text{minimum at }f(1, 1, \cdots, 1) = 0 $ }                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sphere\\(dim = n ) \end{tabular}                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$ \mathbb{R}^{N}$ }    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$f(x_1 \cdots x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ }                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\text{minimum at }f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$ }                                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{}Beale\\( dim = 2 ) \end{tabular}                       & $-4.5 \leq x_i \leq 4.5$                   & $( 1-x+x.y)^{2} + ( 2.25-x+x. y^{2} )^{2} +( 2.625-x+x. y^{2} )^{2} $                                                                                                   & $\text{minimum at }f(3, 0.5) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Alpine\\( dim = n) \end{tabular}                                        & $0 \leq x_i \leq 10$                       & $ \sum_{i=1}^n \mid x_{i}.sin( x_{i} )+0.1.x_{i} \mid $                                                                                                                 & $\text{minimum at }f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                         \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Brown\\( dim = n) \end{tabular}                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$-1 \leq x_i \leq 4$ } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}[(x_{i}^{2})^{(x_{i+1}^{2}+1)} + (x_{i+1}^{2})^{(x_{i}^{2}+1)} ]$ }                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\text{minimum at }f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$ }                                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Schaffer\\( dim = 2 ) \end{tabular}                                     & $-100 \leq x_i \leq 100$                   & $f(x,y)=0.5+\frac{sin({x^2 - y^2})-0.5}{[1+0.001 \cdot (x^2 + y^2)]^2}$                                                                                                 & $\text{minimum at }f(0, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Colville\\( dim = 4) \end{tabular}                                      & $-10 \leq x_i \leq 10$                     & $100( x_{1}^{2} - x_{2} )^{2} + ( x_{1}-1 )^{2} + ( x_{3}-1 )^{2} +90( x_{3}^{2} - x_{4} )^{2}+19.8(x_{2}-1 ).(x_{4}-1 )+10.1(( x_{2} - 1)^{2})+( x_{4} - 1)^{2}))$     & $\text{minimum at }f(1,1,1,1) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\hline
Himmelblau’s                                                                                       & $-6 \leq x_i \leq 6$                       & $ ( x^{2} +y-11)^{2} + (x+ y^{2} -7)^{2} $                                                                                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\text{minimum at }f(3,2) = 0$\\$\text{minimum at }f(-2.805...,3.131) = 0$\\$\text{minimum at }f(-3.779...,-3.283) = 0$\\\\$\text{minimum at }f(3.584...,-1.848) = 0$ \end{tabular}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that the last column isn't shown after compiling.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552550/134144) might be a good place to start from.

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the required packages.

Comment: The formulas in the third column is to wide. You have to break them. Use a `p`-column instead of a `c`-column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could serve as a point to start from:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0.45\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|0c|0c|0l|0l|} 
\hline
Test function & Study domain & Formula & Global minimum at \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{} Rastrigin\\\textasciitilde{}( dim = n ) \end{tabular} & $-5.12 \leq x_i \leq 5.12$                 & $\begin{aligned}f(x_1 \cdots x_n) = 10n + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 -10cos(2\pi x_i))\end{aligned}$                                                                                                       & $f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                        \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{}Ackley\\\textasciitilde{}( dim = 2 ) \end{tabular}     & $-5 \leq x_i \leq 5$  & $\begin{aligned}f(x_0 \cdots x_2) = &-20 exp(-0.2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i^2}) \\&- exp(\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n cos(2\pi x_i)) + 20 + e\end{aligned}$  & $f(0, 0) = 0$ \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{} Rosenbrock\\( dim=n ) \end{tabular}                   & $ \mathbb{R}^{N}$    & $\begin{aligned}f(x_1 \cdots x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (100(x_i^2 - x_{i+1})^2 + (1-x_i)^2)\end{aligned}$                              & $ f(1, 1, \cdots, 1) = 0 $  \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sphere\\(dim = n ) \end{tabular}                                        & $  \mathbb{R}^{N}$     & $\begin{aligned}f(x_1 \cdots x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\end{aligned}$                                                                                                          & $f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textasciitilde{}Beale\\( dim = 2 ) \end{tabular}                       & $-4.5 \leq x_i \leq 4.5$                   & $\begin{aligned} ( 1-x+x.y)^{2} &+ ( 2.25-x+x. y^{2} )^{2} \\&+( 2.625-x+x. y^{2} )^{2} \end{aligned}$                                                                                                   & $f(3, 0.5) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                               \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Alpine\\( dim = n) \end{tabular}                                        & $\phantom{-1}0 \leq x_i \leq 10$                       & $ \sum_{i=1}^n \mid x_{i}.sin( x_{i} )+0.1.x_{i} \mid $                                                                                                                 & $f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                         \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Brown\\( dim = n) \end{tabular}                                         & $-1 \leq x_i \leq 4$  & $\begin{aligned} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}[(x_{i}^{2})^{(x_{i+1}^{2}+1)} + (x_{i+1}^{2})^{(x_{i}^{2}+1)} ]\end{aligned}$                                                                & $f(0, \cdots, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                    \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Schaffer\\( dim = 2 ) \end{tabular}                                     & $-100 \leq x_i \leq 100$                   & $\begin{aligned}f(x,y)=0.5+\frac{sin({x^2 - y^2})-0.5}{[1+0.001 \cdot (x^2 + y^2)]^2}\end{aligned}$                                                                                                 & $f(0, 0) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Colville\\( dim = 4) \end{tabular}                                      & $-10 \leq x_i \leq 10$                     & $\begin{aligned} 100( x_{1}^{2} &- x_{2} )^{2} + ( x_{1}-1 )^{2} + ( x_{3}-1 )^{2} \\&+90( x_{3}^{2} - x_{4} )^{2}+19.8(x_{2}-1 ).(x_{4}-1 )\\&+10.1(( x_{2} - 1)^{2})+( x_{4} - 1)^{2}))\end{aligned}$     & $f(1,1,1,1) = 0$                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\hline
Himmelblau’s                                                                                       & $-6 \leq x_i \leq 6$                       & $ \begin{aligned}( x^{2} +y-11)^{2} + (x+ y^{2} -7)^{2} \end{aligned}$                                                                                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$f(3,2) = 0$\\$f(-2.805...,3.131) = 0$\\$f(-3.779...,-3.283) = 0$\\$f(3.584...,-1.848) = 0$ \end{tabular}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```